# Python get header status for each ahref links found in a class and print link with status code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to extract all href links found within my html within a certain class and print them together with the server header status.

To find each ahref link i have the following

```
for href in soup.find_all('section', class_='holder'):
    for a in href.find_all('a'):
        if a.get('href') == '/':
            continue
        else:
            print(a.get('href'))
```

This prints all the urls ok, but i also want to print the server header status for each next to each url.

Ive tried something like this which doesnt work:

```
for href in soup.find_all('section', class_='holder'):
    for a in href.find_all('a'):
        headers = requests.head('a')
        if a.get('href') == '/':
            continue
        else:
            print(a.get('href'), (headers))
```

My desired output is:

```
https://www.exampleurlone.com/urlone 200
https://www.exampleurlone.com/urltwo 200
https://www.exampleurlone.com/urlthree 404
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need `status_code`.

**Ex:**

```
for href in soup.find_all('section', class_='holder'):
    for a in href.find_all('a'):
        if a.get('href') == '/':
            continue
        else:
            headers = requests.head(a.get('href'))
            print(a.get('href'), (headers.status_code))
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you.